# 'UTF-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 14: invalid continuation byte

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, encoding

I am trying to make a deep neural network but I can't load the data. The way I am trying to load the data is like this:

```
train_path = os.path.join("..", "classification-fruits", "Train")

train_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_path)
```

I can see the subfolders in the code below:

```
categories = sorted(os.listdir(train_path))

# Print the list of subfolders
print("Subfolders in train_path:")
for category in categories:
    print(category)
```

The Output:

Subfolders in train_path:
FreshApple
FreshBanana
FreshGrape
FreshGuava
FreshJujube
FreshOrange
FreshPomegranate
FreshStrawberry
RottenApple
RottenBanana
RottenGrape
RottenGuava
RottenJujube
RottenOrange
RottenPomegranate
RottenStrawberry

The error I am getting:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Furkan Öztürk\Projects\Rotten-Fresh Fruit Detection\Rotten-Fresh-Fruit-Detection\rotten-fresh-fruit-detection.ipynb Cell 11 line 1
----> 1 train_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_path)

File c:\Users\furka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\image_dataset.py:210, in image_dataset_from_directory(directory, labels, label_mode, class_names, color_mode, batch_size, image_size, shuffle, seed, validation_split, subset, interpolation, follow_links, crop_to_aspect_ratio, **kwargs)
    208 if seed is None:
    209     seed = np.random.randint(1e6)
--> 210 image_paths, labels, class_names = dataset_utils.index_directory(
    211     directory,
    212     labels,
    213     formats=ALLOWLIST_FORMATS,
    214     class_names=class_names,
    215     shuffle=shuffle,
    216     seed=seed,
    217     follow_links=follow_links,
    218 )
    220 if label_mode == "binary" and len(class_names) != 2:
    221     raise ValueError(
    222         'When passing `label_mode="binary"`, there must be exactly 2 '
    223         f"class_names. Received: class_names={class_names}"
    224     )

File c:\Users\furka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\dataset_utils.py:542, in index_directory(directory, labels, formats, class_names, shuffle, seed, follow_links)
    540 else:
...
--> 703   return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    704 except errors.OpError:
    705   return False

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd6 in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

What can I do to solve this problem? I really looked into encodings and I couldn't get it into work. Can you guys help?

I've tried to do it like this:

`train_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(train_path.encode("ISO-8859-1"))`

Also I  tried to do it UTF-8 but that didn't work too.